# Bash Regex: Remove charcters from filenames

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, cmd

How we can bulk rename multiple files? What I seek is a regex approach to remove random characters from the beginning of the filenames?

For example suppose I have the following files in a directory

```
_3cc10c0294ce15295e17e737a1d4dde1_C1W2L08.pptx
_7beaa0a223aca1d64505e8382275bb8e_C1W2L09-2.05.53-PM.pptx
_090fd2695e7f30570037a0fae658035a_C1W2L07.pptx
```

and here is what i intend to see:

```
C1W2L08.pptx
C1W2L09-2.05.53-PM.pptx
C1W2L07.pptx
```

Comment: What did you attempt in trying to solve the problem?

Comment: @Inian I rename each file one by one by hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

```
rename 's/_.{32}_//' *.pptx
```

Deletes the underscores and the 32 characters between them.

Comment: Merci for the simple pretty approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.pptx
do
  mv $i ${i#_*_}
done
```

`#{var#prefix}` will remove the prefix; `*` matches a sequence of characters. See more at `man bash`, look for "Parameter Expansion".

Answer (score 0):

This code will select all the files of a similar structure and remove their prefix.

```
for file in _[a-z0-9]*pptx; do
       mv -- "$file" "${file/_*_/}";
done
```